# Difference between 1.constructor and (1).constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, numbers, prototype

Why does `(1).constructor` return `ƒ Number() { [native code] }`, whereas `1.constructor` returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`?

What is the difference between the two and what exactly happens under the hood?

Comment: (1) creates an expression that evaluates to a Number. Hope I got it right this time.

Comment: The parser is greedy and gets as much from the input as it can while the expression it parses is still correct. When it parses `1.constructor`, `1.` is a valid floating point number followed by `constructor` and this breaks the syntax rules. On the other hand, `(1)` is an expression that contains the number `1` between parentheses and `.` is not interpreted as a decimal dot any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your digit is part of a number literal. The first `.` in a numeric literal is the *floating point* and not the start of a property reference.

You can see this [in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals):

> ```
> DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits opt ExponentPart opt
> ```

By wrapping the numeric literal in parentheses, you separate it from the `.` so the `.` is not treated as part of the numeric literal (and so can be used to read a property of the resulting object).

Comment: We got a [boatload of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/9380077?lq=1) for this already…